# Dynamically load in script/code and tie it to bindings

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm not sure how to approach this or if it is even feasible. I am tracking a users hand position and have say their left hand's x and y position. What I would like to be able to do is dynamically load in some loose xaml code which has say a square on a canvas. The position of the square would be bound to the x and y of the user's hand.

Is this possible? And if so, some pointers on where to begin?

Comment: First, you need whatever device that tracks the hand movement to have a public event that is raised every time the X and Y changes. Afterward simply create your WPF, and subscribe to the event of your device. Then it's easy, update the Canvas position based on the new X and Y input that is either sent with the Event or that you're accessing in the Event.

Comment: Yup I can do all that, what I want do do is dynamically load in some WPF xaml code and be able to bind to the x and y input.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand why you would need/want to do that? I Guess the device can handle two hands at Once and so you'd want two Canvas in this case?

Comment: I don't think I'm being clear enough. I have the variables for the hands, I have an empty content control in the WPF App, I want to dynamically load a xaml file or something similar which defines a user control which binds to these variables and events.

Comment: By dynamic I mean literally load some loose xaml from disc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataTemplate` and `Trigger` are what you're looking for.

[Data Templating Overview on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)

[Really good example on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18303/A-Guided-Tour-of-WPF-Part-4-Data-templates-and-tri)

Basically you'll want to create a `DataTemplate` for your Input and add Triggers for your X & Y Attributes so that you can move the `Canvas` so the right Location.

This will also support a dynamic amount of input (1,2,3,etc hands).

Good luck!

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for. See the additional comment I just added :)

Comment: The right approach would be DataTemplate, given you have all the variables at hands. That's as far as my knowledge goes but you can check this link out: [Load XAML at Runtime](http://www.mostlydevelopers.com/blog/post/2009/01/15/load-xaml-at-runtime.aspx)

Comment: That link is kinda more what I am looking for. Cheers.